# New line list in python

Tags: python

How can I create a list that starts in a new line because right now my menu looks like this:

> Choose index in [(0, 'Display ID'), (1, 'Display Balance'), (2,
>   'Display Annual Interest Rate'), (3, 'Display Monthly Interest Rate'),
>   (4, 'Display Monthly Interest'), (5, 'Withdraw Money'), (6, 'Deposit
>   Money'), (7, 'Exit')]

and I need it to look like this:

> Choose index in    (0) Display ID
>
> (1) Display Balance
>
> (2) Display Annual Interest Rate
>
> (3) Display Monthly Interest Rate
>
> (4) Display Monthly Interest
>
> (5) Withdraw Money
>
> (6) Deposit Money
>
> (7) Exit

I have tried using '\n'.join but it doesn't work.

```
 actions = ["Display ID",
               "Display Balance",
               "Display Annual Interest Rate",
               "Display Monthly Interest Rate",
               "Display Monthly Interest",
               "Withdraw Money",
               "Deposit Money",
               "Exit"]
        while True:
            choice = int(input("Choose index in " + str(list(enumerate(actions)))))
            apply_actions(choice, acc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```py
choice = int(input("Choose index in " + str(list(enumerate(actions)))))
```

Do:

```py
print("Choose index in ")
for i, action in enumerate(actions):
    print("(" + str(i) + ") " + action)
```

Alternatively:

```py
print("Choose index in \n" + "\n".join(["(" + str(i+1) + ") " + action for i, action in enumerate(actions)]))
```

Comment: With the alternative code it is giving me a "TypeError: apply_actions() missing 1 required positional argument: 'account'"

Comment: @User3230 that would be something you've done/changed!  this answer doesn't refer to `apply_actions` at all

Comment: @SamMason The things is that with the code provided, the action "choice" is not include. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: you still need to call `input()` somewhere!  mario was showing you how to format the prompt in the way you requested